# Set default toggle to be checked in ion-toggle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ion-toggle

Below is the code to list toggle buttons in  which I want to set the first toggle button to be on and the rest off..

```
<ion-view view-title="Choose language">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list"> 
      <ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in lists" ng-model="item.checked"   
        ng-checked="item.checked">
        {{ item.name }}   
      </ion-toggle>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

   $scope.lists= [
                { name: 'List1' },
                { name: 'List2' },
                { name: 'List3' },
            ];
```

I tried by giving **$scope.item.checked='List1'** but didn't work.Any possible solutions for this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup the `item` in the repeat is the object in the `lists` array.

Try this. Replace the `$scope.lists` by this object.

```
$scope.lists = [
    { name: "List1", checked: false },
    { name: "List2", checked: true },
    { name: "List3", checked: false }
  ];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

For the toggle to be always ON by default respective of the model:

```
<ion-toggle item-right (ionChange)="someMethod($event.checked)" checked="{{somebooleanmodel}}"></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: just focus on checked poperty

Answer (score 0):

For the toggle to be always ON by default irrespective of the model, set:

```
<ion-toggle ng-checked="true" ng-model="someModel">
  {{expression}}   
</ion-toggle>
```